# Opening a UIViewController from a UIAlertView within a UIStoryBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

How can I open a new `UIViewController` (ViewController4) with a `UIAlertView` within a `UIStoryBoard`?

Answer (score 0):

Give an Identifier to the viewcontroller in the storyboard.

On the delegate method for the uialertview ([the one that sets the behavior of pressing a button](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html)) do the following:

- Instantiate the viewcontroller retrieving it by asking the "storyboard" to give you the controller with the identifier. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- Present this viewcontroller modaly. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Comment: it returns now  <ViewController4: 0xcec30a0> i try to do now the second step - presenting the viewcontroller modaly

Comment: lol, read the documentation, it is super simple if you go to the apple examples, im not on my mac so i dont really remember the methods but if you already got the viewcontroller retrieved, like Viewcontroller4 *tempcontroler4 = [Storyboard something something... then you just have to present it with [self presentmodalviewcontroller: tempcontroler4] THis sintaxis is wrong but xcode should help you correct it

Comment: Thanks Oscar, but this was the first thing i tried 3 days ago :D ... the right synthax was      [self presentalModalViewController:view4 animated:YES]; and this do not work from the appdelegate file were i want to call the method

Comment: then its very simple, and apple shows it in their examples. send your delegate the viewcontroller who is going to present in the same method where your delegate. this way you can use the viewcontroller that you specified to present the modal view and it should display it. (basically add a variable to your delegate so that he knows which viewcontroller will be the one presenting the modal view). If youw ant to see the example see how the imagepicker works.

Comment: man, i have the  imagepicker already working, i appreciate your help, but i need some code snippet which i can apply to my project ... i realized it at the moment with       -(void) perform4 { all the stuff above and then       </br>       [self.window.rootViewController.view = view4.view;      [self.window makeKeyVisible];     thanks it, i switch the view with this at the moment